# OpenSSL link options -lssl and -lcrypto in GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, openssl

After adding the link options: -lssl and -lcrypto, my program was correctly compiled.
However, I found GCC doesn't include the two options, so where do the options come from?

Comment: Releated, see [Errors that refer to a bunch of unresolved OpenSSL symbols that clearly exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15318978).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) tells us that `-l` is the option to link with a library.

```
-llibrary
-l library
Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the
library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not
recommended.)
```

So you're telling gcc to link with the libraries "ssl" and "crypto".  These libraries are typically installed in `/usr/lib`.  On Linux they'll be called `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so`.  On OS X they'll be called `libssl.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib`.

Comment: On Cygwin they'll be called libssl.a and libcrypto.a

Comment: For static linking use additional parameters like this **-static -lcrypto -lz -ldl -static-libgcc** (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811538/4410376)