# How to include the basic header files which are available with C in UNIX?

Tags: c, unix, header-files, turbo-c

When we work on Turbo C, we get all the functions and header files by default which we can include normally by
    #inlcude 
eg: stdlib.h, math.h

But when writing a simple program using such header files I am getting error because I'm unable to include these files. Aren't these header files available by default for us to use?
If yes then how to use such header files?
When I used a function sqrt in "math.h" I was getting error as math.h was not getting included so I had to include it in the following command:

```
cc -c aaa.c -I/usr/local/ssl/include
gcc -o aaa aaa.c -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lcrypto -lm
./aaa
```

In this command the 2nd one is having **-lm** at the end to include math.h

again similarly I used a function itoa() which is in *stdlib.h*
which I am executing on a UNIX Solaris server, but it is not getting included and I am gettig error. Now I don't know how to add this header file.

Comment: I think you are confusing including header files and linking with shared libraries.

Comment: `-lm` will link to the math library not include math.h

Comment: Are you actually `#include`ing the header files in your source code?

Comment: Do you include `"math.h"` or `<math.h>` ?

Answer (score 3):

The `math.h` header is included normally. The code can compile. However, the compiler won't find the compiled binary (the implementation of math.h) to **link** to unless you specify it to do so. So you have to specify -lm in the command.

`itoa()` is not a standard function in `stdlib.h`, so do not use it. You can use sprintf instead.

Comment: I want to get the ascii code of every individual character in a string like this "AB12" in hex like this "41 42 31 32". Will sprintf serve my purpose? And I also checked in the turbo c documentation. itoa() is there in the stdlib.h

Comment: It may be in stdlib.h of Turbo C, but it is not in the standard of stdlib.h. Support for itoa may or may not be available cross-platform, so it is safer to use whatever is standard. If you want to convert from string to long, you have strtol. If you want to convert from int/long to string, use printf or sprintf (depending on your purpose).

Comment: How does one find out what is the name of the file to link to?
Like I linked the math.h's implementation file by   -lm   
I have to include another header file which is in crypto library of openssl.
I want to know if I have a header file what would be the name of its implementation file and how to link it?

Comment: I think you can find the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829670/openssl-link-options-lssl-and-lcrypto-in-gcc

Answer (score 0):

your compiler should provide command line settings where you can specify include directories, library directories etc. it is best if you take a look at your compiler documentation.

E.g. visual studio has a command switch -I to specify include folders

alt. in some cases it can be specified as an environment variable e.g. set INCLUDE=...

it all depends on what compiler you use.

Comment: But why including the header file in the code itself doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

By default these are standard library functions that are exported from libc and they should be available in any Unix/Linux flavor. You can check where the header file exists using command like

```
find / -name "stdio.h" 2>/dev/null
```

Also make sure you link to libc using
    -l libc

Also, which compiler are you using? I suggest you use gcc, that way the include config is already done for the compiler, you can use it as is and get going.