# C++ linker has problems finding openssl MD4 function

Tags: c++, c, linker, include

I have a program that I am writing and that needs to calculate some hashes. I need SHA, MD, HMAC algorithms. That is why I chose `openssl` as solution.

My code is the following:

```
#include <openssl/md4.h>

void calc();

void calc(unsigned char* data, unsigned long len) {
  unsigned char* h = new unsigned char[128];
  MD4(data, len, h);
}
```

Compiler returns me the following:

> myfile.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `MD4' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

I compile simply using:

```
g++ myfile.cpp -o myapp.o
```

under Linux Fedora.

I downloaded `openssl` libraries from [here](http://www.openssl.org/source/) and compiled them cby using `./configure` and then `make install` in the downloaded untarpalled directory. I also copied in `/usr/local/include` directory the `include` directory in the one I downloaded so that headers can be found by compiler because `/usr/local/include` is in my `$PATH` env var.

However the problem is that the linker cannot find the function. I understand that the reason might be two:

- The compiler can find headers but cannot find implementations.
- There are problems because `openssl` is written in `C` not in `C++`.

How should I proceeed? Thankyou

### Edit1

I actually changed something in my `openssl installation`.

I installed `openssl` again and I could see that it places everything under `/usr/local/ssl` where I can find `/usr/local/ssl/include` and `/usr/local/ssl/lib` directories. I change my compilation string in:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

In the directories that I mentioned before I can find, respectively, `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl` directory with all headers there and `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a` and `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a` libraries.

Before I did this change when I used the old compilation command, the compiler was telling me: `Cannot find -lssl`. With these changes, now it can find libs and headers, but `ld` always fails in the same way:

> myfile.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `MD4' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

A little disappointed.
What do you think?

Comment: You probably need to specify the name of the library in your compile command: `g++ myfile.cpp openssl-something -o myapp.o`, perhaps even include the path to the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking against `openssl` usually requires `-lssl`.

```
g++ -o myapp myfile.cpp -lssl
```

By the way, it sounds like you may have done the installation a little incorrectly.

You shouldn't have to copy header files anywhere. And you may not have copied the shared libraries anyway.

The compilation should go something like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openssl
make
make install
```

And then you compile your program like:

```
g++ -c -o myapp1.o myfile1.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include
g++ -c -o myapp2.o myfile2.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include
g++ -o myapp myapp1.o myapp2.o -I/usr/local/openssl/include -L/usr/local/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: I do what you told me, after fixing the installation ad providing correct L and I options and l options adding crypto as well, it can find those headers and implementations because the compiler tells me no more that it cannot find `lssl`, but the same problem persists...

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. That is very strange. What happens if you run `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version` on the command line?

Comment: It tells me `OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012`

Comment: It corresponds to the version I installed from the link I posted in the question.

Comment: And if you do `/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl list-message-digest-commands` it shows `md4`?

Comment: Is it something related to C functions that the linker cannot link because of differences between C and C++? You know those errors related to `extern "C"` stuff... but I do not know what to think about this...

Comment: You only have the static libraries installed. When linking statically, order of the libraries makes a huge difference. Try... `g++ myapp.o -o myapp -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto`

Comment: So make sure the `crypto` and `ssl` libraries are listed after your own object files.

Comment: Compile `.cpp` files first with the `-c` flag. I updated the example in my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: Sorry Geoff, I did not mention it, but I have more files to compile... it tells me I cannot compile with -c option multiple files...

Comment: Yes. You have to compile each `.cpp` file individually with `-c`.

Comment: Updated the example to give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: It compiled successfully... please could you explain what exactly you did please? Why is it working now? Which was the problem here? Thankyou btw...

Comment: When you are using static libraries, the GNU linker has to have them in order of their dependency, if lib A requires lib B, then it needs to see them as `-lA -lB`. Since your `myapp.o` required `-lssl -lcrypt`, it needed to see `myapp.o -lssl -lcrypt`.

Comment: I see Geoff, thak you very much for spending your time on my problem. Before I forgot to check your answer as correct, sorry for being late. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because you do not link the program to the openssl library during compilation.

Fix it with

```
g++ myfile.cpp -o myapp.o -lssl
```

See [OpenSSL link options -lssl and -lcrypto in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829670/openssl-link-options-lssl-and-lcrypto-in-gcc)

for how to link a program to openssl.