# Errors that refer to a bunch of unresolved OpenSSL symbols that clearly exist?

Tags: gcc, static-linking, nm

I am building a shared library (we'll call it "foo") that makes use of another library (we'll call it "bar"). "bar" makes use of some functions from OpenSSL.

Here's where the problem surfaces.

"bar" was compiled as a static library and it would appear that OpenSSL was too. So when I link the library ("foo"), I include the:

- object files for "foo"
- static library `libbar.a`
- OpenSSL static libraries `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a`

The build command looks something like this:

```
g++ -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -shared file1.o file2.o libbar.a \
  libcrypto.a libssl.a -o libfoo.so
```

However, I get a ton of errors:

```
ld: ./obj/libbar.a(file1.c.o): in function initialize_openssl:
  ssl.c:117: error: undefined reference to 'SSL_library_init'
```

Running the following command:

```
nm libssl.a | grep SSL_library_init
```

Produces the following output:

```
00000000 T SSL_library_init
```

So obviously there is nothing wrong with the OpenSSL libraries. What could have possibly caused something like this? Here are the three commands used to build OpenSSL:

```
export cross=arm-linux-androideabi-
./Configure android --prefix=~/openssl-arm
make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib"
```

The compilation process completed without any errors, so I'm utterly baffled.

Why am I getting linker errors that refer to a bunch of OpenSSL symbols that clearly exist?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was caused by the *order of the libraries in the link command.* Switching the order of `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` resolved all of the symbols.

GCC uses `LD` by default, and its a single pass linker. When you have two libraries, like `libssl` and `libcrypto` linked in a particular order, it means `libssl` depends on symbols from `libcrypto`. Therefore, `libssl` must precede `libcrypto` (or `libcrypto` must follow `libssl`). It should be no surprise `libssl` relies upon `libcrypto` since `libcrypto` provides the crypto used by `libssl`.

Comment: I'm guessing because the compiler/linker learn the symbols in a linear order and if an out of order condition happens then it barfs.  It could even be reverse-linear (anticipating bar depending on foo and your dependency constructions being built backwards).