# No reference to BIO-functions when linking OpenSSL

Tags: c, linux, ssl, compilation, openssl

I'm trying to compile a c-program with openssl-references. I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 and the development package "libssl-dev" is installed.

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
...

void send_smtp_request(BIO *bio, const char *req)
{
    BIO_puts(bio, req);
    BIO_flush(bio);
    printf("%s", req);     
}
```

If I compile the code with:

```
gcc -o client bio-ssl-smtpcli2.c
```

I get the this error:

```
/tmp/ccCHrti2.o: In function 'send_smtp_request':
bio-ssl-smtpcli2.c:(.text+0x1f):  undefined reference to 'BIO_puts'
bio-ssl-smtpcli2.c:(.text+0x3a):  undefined reference to 'BIO_ctrl'
```

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking problem of OpenSSL library in existing C project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700617/linking-problem-of-openssl-library-in-existing-c-project), [Linking OpenSSLs libcrypto in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18835219), [Errors that refer to a bunch of unresolved OpenSSL symbols that clearly exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15318978), ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I managed to compile your function by using :

```
gcc main.c -o main -I /usr/local/ssl/include -L /usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -Wall
```

More explainations :

- `-I /usr/local/ssl/include` adds `/usr/local/ssl/include` to the include search path.
- `-L /usr/local/ssl/lib` adds `/usr/local/ssl/lib` to the library search path.
- `-lssl -lcrypto` links libraries libcrypto and libssl
- `-lcrypto` must follow `-lssl` becuase ld is a single pass linker
- `Wall` enables all warnings.

My guess is that you are missing `-lcrypto`.

Comment: I got a new error:                                                                                /usr/local/ssl/lib//libssl.a(ssl_lib.o): In function `SSL_clear':  ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'

Comment: I found [this answer to the same problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-985136.html) : try to put `-lssl` in front of `-lcrypto`. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok no errors anymore :) To complete the answer, I had to add -ldl

Answer (score 0):

`put -lssl in front of -lcrypto` the solved my issue, thanks!