# OpenSSL linking undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new' and others

Tags: gcc, openssl, undefined-reference

I am compiling some codes based on OpenSSL. The compiler, parameters and error are shown in the following.

```
$ gcc -I/home/share/pkp/include -L/home/share/pkp/lib -lssl -lcrypto -Wall -O3 -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-result -Wno-pointer-sign ot.c -o ot
/tmp/cck3sgve.o: In function `main':
ot.c:(.text.startup+0x20): undefined reference to     `EVP_get_digestbyname'
ot.c:(.text.startup+0x31): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
ot.c:(.text.startup+0x41): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit_ex'
ot.c:(.text.startup+0x53): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal_ex'
ot.c:(.text.startup+0x5b): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here are versions of components in the compile environments.

```
$ uname -a
Linux yzx-lab3 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #379-Microsoft Wed Mar 06 19:16:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ /home/share/pkp/bin/openssl version
./bin/openssl: relocation error: ./bin/openssl: symbol EVP_mdc2 version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
$ grep "OPENSSL_VERSION" /home/share/pkp/openssl-1.1.1a/include/openssl/opensslv.h
# define OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER  0x1010101fL
# define OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT    "OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018"
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I know there already many question about the similar error and have tried many solutions. But they do not work.

1) Fist I obtain the source code and unzip all the fils to "/home/share/pkp".

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1a.tar.gz
```

Then compile and install openssl library.

```
./config --prefix=/home/share/pkp --openssldir=/home/share/pkp/openssl
    make && make test && make install
```

There is no error message during the installation.

2) To asure that openssl is compiled and installed correctly, I do some verifications.

```
$ ls /home/share/pkp/lib/ -l
total 14912
drwxrwxrwx 1 share share    4096 Jun 18 12:30 engines-1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 share share 5700252 Jun 18 12:30 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 share share      16 Jun 18 12:30 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 share share 3414744 Jun 18 12:30 libcrypto.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 share share 1043216 Jun 18 12:30 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 share share      13 Jun 18 12:30 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 share share  692696 Jun 18 12:30 libssl.so.1.1
$ nm /home/share/pkp/lib/libcrypto.a | grep "EVP_get_digestbyname" | wc -l
24
$ du /home/share/pkp/include/openssl -ah
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/aes.h
36K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/asn1.h
0       /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/asn1_mac.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/asn1err.h
36K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/asn1t.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/async.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/asyncerr.h
36K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/bio.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/bioerr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/blowfish.h
24K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/bn.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/bnerr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/buffer.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/buffererr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/camellia.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/cast.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/cmac.h
20K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/cms.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/cmserr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/comp.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/comperr.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/conf.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/conf_api.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/conferr.h
20K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/crypto.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/cryptoerr.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ct.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/cterr.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/des.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/dh.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/dherr.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/dsa.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/dsaerr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/dtls1.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/e_os2.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ebcdic.h
64K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ec.h
0       /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ecdh.h
0       /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ecdsa.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ecerr.h
36K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/engine.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/engineerr.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/err.h
76K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/evp.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/evperr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/hmac.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/idea.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/kdf.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/kdferr.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/lhash.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/md2.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/md4.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/md5.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/mdc2.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/modes.h
216K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/obj_mac.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/objects.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/objectserr.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ocsp.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ocsperr.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/opensslv.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pem.h
0       /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pem2.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pemerr.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pkcs12.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pkcs12err.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pkcs7.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/pkcs7err.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rand.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rand_drbg.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/randerr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rc2.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rc4.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rc5.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ripemd.h
24K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rsa.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/rsaerr.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/safestack.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/seed.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/sha.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/srp.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/srtp.h
112K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ssl.h
0       /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ssl2.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ssl3.h
48K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/sslerr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/stack.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/store.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/storeerr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/symhacks.h
72K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/tls1.h
24K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ts.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/tserr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/txt_db.h
16K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/ui.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/uierr.h
4.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/whrlpool.h
44K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/x509.h
32K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h
8.0K    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/x509err.h
36K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/x509v3.h
12K     /home/share/pkp/include/openssl/x509v3err.h
1.6M    /home/share/pkp/include/openssl
```

3)Finally, I tried other compile commands, but then still do not work.

```
$ gcc -I/home/share/pkp/include -L/home/share/pkp/lib -lcrypto -lssl -Wall -O3 -Wpedantic -Wno-unuse
d-result -Wno-pointer-sign ot.c -o ot
$ gcc -I/home/share/pkp/include -L/home/share/pkp/lib -lssl -lcrypto -Wall -O3 -Wpedantic -Wno-unuse
d-result -Wno-pointer-sign ot.c -o ot
$ gcc -I/home/share/pkp/include -L/home/share/pkp/lib -lcrypto -lssl -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-unuse
d-result -Wno-pointer-sign ot.c -o ot
$ gcc -I/home/share/pkp/include -L/home/share/pkp/lib -lcrypto -O3 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wno-unuse
d-result -Wno-pointer-sign ot.c -o ot
```

4) It seems that the openssl from downloaded source code is conflict with the openssl installed by "apt-get". So I try another method.

```
./config && make && make test && make install
```

It will install openssl into the system directory. Then I run

```
$ gcc -lssl -lcrypto ot.c -o ot
/tmp/ccrFwoa7.o: In function `main':
ot.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
ot.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
ot.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit_ex'
ot.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal_ex'
ot.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It still failed. Envn I follow the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185618/how-to-use-static-linking-with-openssl-in-c-c) trying to statically link libcrypto and libssl. It failed again.

```
$ gcc -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -static -static-libgcc ot.c -o ot
/tmp/cc39C5Gq.o: In function `main':
ot.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
ot.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
ot.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit_ex'
ot.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal_ex'
ot.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am sure all the static libraries are in the correct location.

```
$ whereis lib{ssl,crypto,z,dl}.a
libssl: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/local/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/lib/libssl.so
libcrypto: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so /mnt/c/Windows/System32/libcrypto.dll
libz: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
libdl: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
```

5) Come here to post this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
const EVP_MD *md;
unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
int md_len, i;

md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]);
if(!md) {
    printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}

mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

printf("Digest is: ");
for (i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
    printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
printf("\n");

exit(0);
}
```

The code should be compiled with no error. But now it shows "undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'".

Comment: Did you try to put the library "-lcrypto -lssl" in the end of the compiling command?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the libraries in the end of the compiling command, like this:

`gcc -I/home/share/pkp/include -L/home/share/pkp/lib -Wall -O3 -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-result -Wno-pointer-sign ot.c -o ot -lcrypto -lssl`

You can know why here: [Why does the library linker flag sometimes have to go at the end using GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc)

I reproduced the error in my machine and this change solved it.